# Multiple where() calls or associative array in code igniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, activerecord

I have a query that has this as part of it:

```
$this->db->where(array(
                 'jobs.open_intentions' => 1,
                 'jobs.open'            => 1, 
                 'jobs.pending'         => 0,
                 'jobs.awarded'         => 0));
```

Which works fine, but I don't like that format, actually I would much rather write it like

```
$this->db->where('jobs.open_intentions', 1) 
         ->where('jobs.open', 1) 
         ->where('jobs.pending', 0)
         ->where('jobs.awarded', 0);
```

Nit picking I know, but anyway, my question is, is there any reason I should choose one method over the other or is it just a matter of preference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Semantically speaking, the latter (multiple `where`s) feels more like multiple `AND`-clauses to me. With the former, the intent is unclear (without looking at the API docs).

Comment: That's basically how I feel as well, i think it is much easier to glance at the second version and know what's going on, I need to think about the first version for a second, but I am wondering if there is any performance issues (although assumedly micro-optimization) that I should be aware of?

Comment: Beware hasty pre-optimization! :P

Answer (score 1):

Although later method is commonly used but for the sake of simplicity and clear code you can do like this too

```
$where  =    array(
             'jobs.open_intentions' => 1,
             'jobs.open'            => 1, 
             'jobs.pending'         => 0,
             'jobs.awarded'         => 0
             );
$this->db->where($where);
```

Comment: I see no benefit to this method

Comment: it is only a matter of preference  i usually use arrays for select and then unset them but in where instruction the later one i follow

Answer (score 0):

There is one advantage i see in the later one which is you can use different where clauses e.g. or_where, where_in, or_where_in with clean code which is pretty difficult in the earlier one. But if you are using a single operator then both are same.